# NHibernate Session.Merge() not mapped properties

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way in NHibernate to "manually" merge not hibernate mapped properties?

My problem is that I have a property that is set when the entity is loaded from the database. After merging the entity to another session the value of that property is wrong because hibernate merges mapped properties only.

Maybe it is possible to overload something like OnMerge(obj entityMergeFrom, object EntityMergeTo) method somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered similar issues with NHibernate, and without code I an assuming lazy loading is enabled. To get around this, I have implemented a function to dodge the current session context. I hope that this helps. What this does is get the current session and remove the entity from the context. It then creates a new session to get the object by ID then disposes of the context. Finally we merge the "fresh" entity into the current context. If you would like to preserve values not saved, you may have to add additional logic.

```
    public T GetNotFromCache(Guid id, ISession session)
    {
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(NHibernate.SessionManager.GetFactory()))
        {
            // the session with unmapped data is passed here.
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(NHibernate.SessionManager.OpenSession());
        }

        T item = (T)session.Get<T>(id);
        session.Evict(item);
        T entity = null;

        // create a new session to assign the entity and dispose of it within this context
        using (ISession newSession = NHibernate.SessionManager.OpenNewSession())
        {
            entity = (T)newSession.Get<T>(id);
        } 

        // Merge and bind to the preferred session then do a get within the context.
        session.Merge<T>(entity);
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(NHibernate.SessionManager.OpenSession());
        entity = session.Get<T>(id);

        return entity;
    }
```